# UV mapping - Comes in reverse and then mis-wraps to other parts of the bottle

Tags: uv

I tried to uv map a liquor label onto a bottle and it comes in reverse.. fine... so to compensate I reverse the png file so it's shown correctly.. however now the label shows up on the side of bottle too.. which of course was NOT part of the UV faces I selected. Any ideas how to fix please?

The png label and blend file are here:  http://www.aworkofmarc.com/1/blender/teeling

[image]

Comment: It's not necessary to rotate the image so to map it on the model in different ways. You can select adjacent UV map island as it's reverted, press `S` > `Y` > `-1` to invert it by Y axis.

Comment: The label shows across all the bottle because this UV map consists not only from front UV island. There are others for all the parts of the bottle, so the image is mapped on those parts too. I'd recommend using masking - paint on the model parts where label should be and use it as a Factor input

Comment: Can you direct me to where or how I do "masking - paint on the model parts where label should be and use it as a Factor input"  Sorry I'm so painfully new / inept.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19039/how-do-you-overlay-an-image-on-a-shader-in-cycles. The only thing you are left to do is to create a mask (black - no image shown, white where image should be seen)

Comment: Also related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7476/cycles-compositor-apply-color-balance-node-only-on-a-part-of-image